# Windows 7 BSOD when playing games

Tags: windows-7, bsod, gaming

I get a blue screen of death from almost any game I play (only from games). I can run the computer for days with no problem as long as I don't start any games. The BSOD is

```
KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR

STOP: 0x7A (0xFFFFF6FC400097E0, 0xFFFFFFFFC000009D, 0x0000000009B76086, 0xFFFFF880012FC758)

Ntfs.sys - Address FFFFF880012FC758 base at FFFFF8800120E000 DateStamp 0xFFFFF880012FC758
```

Sometimes a different screen comes up but that is the most common. I'm pulling this from a picture on my phone.

This error occurs on every game I've played so far EXCEPT Borderlands 2. I've run harddrive health checks and come up with nothing. I've purchased and used a power supply tester and everything was green. I have literally no idea what could be causing this.

Hardware Specs:
CPU: Intel Core i7 2600
Motherboard: Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd.
RAM: 16GB DDR3
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 570
HDD: 2 3TB 7200RPM Seagate Barracuda

Any lead on even what I could look at would be helpful at this point. At some point my gaming group is going to finish Borderlands 2 and I would like to be able to play something else.

Comment: `KERNER_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR` suggests something's gone wrong memory-wise. Try and run Memtest86+ for at least two full passes (might take a while): http://www.memtest.org/. Install on a bootable medium (CD/USB) and boot from that. If no errors come up, let me know, otherwise try a different set of memory sticks.

Comment: Go download [Blue Screen View](http://download.cnet.com/BlueScreenView/3000-2094_4-10965136.html), it is a free tool that will let you get the text from previous bluescreens, the system tries to save the information if it can. Get the text from the other bluescreens so we can compare what the different screens say.

Comment: What are the specs on your power supply? Your video card will be pulling a lot of current under load this and may be the underlying problem. Did the power supply tester work when the computer was running a game? What did it actually tell you?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your filesystem. If your page file is stored on a different volume than the one you boot with (usually `C:`) you might be able to do an online chkdsk. But if you have multiple drives/volumes, Windows tends to distribute the page file across all of them and you should check all of your volumes (including one on your boot volume, which will require you to reboot). Alternatively, you could disable the page file altogether. 16 GiB of RAM is more than sufficient to do this, I have 32 GiB of RAM w/ an 8 GiB RAM disk mounted most of the time and I still disable paging.

Answer (score 1):

`KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR` means that [Windows can't read data from the pagefile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The error C000009D means `STATUS_DEVICE_NOT_CONNECTED`. So Windows lost the HDD and can't read the data. Try different SATA cables.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1.**
Run the Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool. Not sure will that work because this is to check the memory.
**Method 2.** Type "cmd" at search and run Command Prompt as administrator. Then do the following command: `sfc /scannow`.
**Method 3.** Check can you boot into safe mode. If  not: boot from Windows 7 CD/USB installation drive. As you get "Windows 7 Install now" don't click Install Now. Press "Repair your computer". Get Command Prompt and do following commands:
`chkdsk /f /r
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
bootrec /scanos`After you done it, boot into Safe Mode and go to Drivers. Click on Sound Card, Video Adapter and Network Adapter and disable one by one. Boot normally and try enabling them.